# Limit paragraph text using css

Tags: html, css, overflow, ellipsis

I want to limit my paragraph to five lines and want to add read more link after that. (That link direct to another page). I want to do it using CSS and i tried following examples, but they are not working for me.

http://jsfiddle.net/csYjC/1131/

http://jsfiddle.net/csYjC/1122/

http://joelsaupe.com/programming/multiple-line-ellipsis-css/

I can limit it only one line using `white-space: nowrap;`

Why this isn't work? What is the best way to do this?

Any help highly appriciate.
Thanks,

Comment: like this http://jsfiddle.net/csYjC/4411/

Comment: @Leothelion i tried it. But it's not woking

Comment: Check my fiddle...working there..or share the demo where its not working.

Comment: @Leothelion it's woking now. I have override some css class. I want to know one thing. Is there any possible way to add a " read more " link after that 3 dots.

Comment: if you are ok with jquery then see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16058483/how-do-i-add-a-read-more-link-at-the-end-of-a-paragraph)